# JSON Object validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, validation

I am using JSON object as an input in the textfield. Is there any way to validate this JSON object in JavaScript??

Comment: Are you trying to validate that it's syntactically valid JSON or that it conforms to a certain schema?

Comment: I am just trying to check whether the object entered in textfield is valid JSON.

Comment: you can use intval function for example $id=intval($id); echo json_encode($data)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Building on the idea of @Quentin, you can just do something like:

```
function isValidJson(json) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(json);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(isValidJson("{}")); // true
console.log(isValidJson("abc")); // false
```

This will require [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to be deployed in the page in order to ensure cross-browser support for the `JSON` `Object`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I am getting an error for valid JSON object also.

Comment: {
"id":"b9c8e5f2-50ae-102c-8da0-dv8gb9f250ae",
"at":2,
"tmax":100,
"imp":
[
{
"impid":"dv8gb9f2-50ae-102c-8da0-12313a002cd2",
"h":50,
"w":320,
"instl":0
}
],
"app":
{
"aid":"73737",
"name":"We Rule",
"ver":"2.1.3"
},
"device":
{
"dpid":"dfe9f2bdfe9f2bdfe9f2bdfe9f2bdfe9f2bdfe9f2b",
"ip":"124.32.53.1",
"ua":"Mozilla%2F5.0%20(iPhone%3B%20U%3B%20CPU%20iPhone"
}
}

Comment: It appears to work for me, have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2ufR/).

Comment: I am using this function on "onsubmit". Should this be a problem??

Comment: Shouldn't be. Is it possible to set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the scenario in which the code is failing?

Comment: It worked. I was not passing correct value to the function.Thank u for ur help.

Comment: Its giving me an error for the same JSON string in IE compatibility view.

Comment: Have you got [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) included in your page?

Comment: It doesn't work when you put numbers as an input. For example: console.log(isValidJson("123")); // true
I think we need also check if input is a number.

Comment: @user3816621 A number string is a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 3):

if you wish to validate the object to a certain schema, you could try [JSD Validator](http://www.build-software.nl/JSDValidator/)

Answer (score 0):

Run it through a JSON parser ([json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you aren't using a library with one built in) and see if you get data back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are quite a few JSON libraries available for your use.

Try these out when using Java:

- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) - A High performance JSON processors
- [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) -  Java library by google

Or if you prefer simple JavaScript, you can go with

- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
- [Mootools](http://mootools.net/)

[David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/) has given a full example of how to do this in javascript using Mootools, JSON Schema, in the following blog http://davidwalsh.name/json-validation. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me,

```
$scope.jsonFunc = function(json){
        try {
            $scope.jsonData = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json), null, 2);
            return true;
            $scope.errorMessage = "Valid JSON";
        } catch (e) {
            $scope.errorMessage = e.message;
            return false;
        }
}
```