# How to best validate JSON on the server-side

Tags: json, web-services, validation, api, security

When handling POST, PUT, and PATCH requests on the server-side, we often need to process some JSON to perform the requests.

It is obvious that we need to validate these JSONs (e.g. structure, permitted/expected keys, and value types) in some way, and I can see at least two ways:

1. Upon receiving the JSON, **validate the JSON upfront as it is**, **before** doing anything with it to complete the request.
2. Take the JSON as it is, start processing it (e.g. access its various key-values) and **try to validate it on-the-go while performing business logic**, and possibly use some exception handling to handle vogue data.

The 1st approach seems more robust compared to the 2nd, but probably more expensive (in time cost) because every request will be validated (and hopefully most of them are valid so the validation is sort of redundant).

The 2nd approach may save the compulsory validation on valid requests, but mixing the checks within business logic might be buggy or even risky.

Which of the two above is better? Or, is there yet a better way?

Comment: The 1st approach is also more robust for future refactoring.

Comment: I suggest divide your validations. On upfront validation , only validate the for basic (data-type, null ,size) criteria . On business layer, validate for business correctness (for e.g. whether the codes supplied are correct ) on the go. Modularize the validation code in business  layer, I do not think that would be buggy/risky.

Comment: What web framework are you using?

Comment: @Sdra, Tornado (python)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I upvoted everyone as I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are describing with POST, PUT, and PATCH sounds like you are implementing a REST API. Depending on your back-end platform, you can use libraries that will map JSON to objects which is very powerful and performs that validation for you. In JAVA, you can use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400233/spring-mvc-requestmapping-from-json), or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). If you are using .NET, you can use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

If efficiency is your goal and you want to validate every single request, it would be ideal if you could evaluate on the front-end if you are using JavaScript you can use [json2.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431415/json-object-validation-in-javascript).

In regards to comparing your methods, here is a Pro / Cons list.

### Method #1: Upon Request

**Pros**

1. The business logic integrity is maintained. As you mentioned trying to validate while processing business logic could result in invalid tests that may actually be valid and vice versa or also the validation could inadvertently impact the business logic negatively.
2. As Norbert mentioned, catching the errors before hand will improve efficiency. The logical question this poses is why spend the time processing, if there are errors in the first place?
3. The code will be cleaner and easier to read. Having validation and business logic separated will result in cleaner, easier to read and maintain code.

**Cons**

1. It could result in redundant processing meaning longer computing time.

### Method #2: Validation on the Go

**Pros**

1. It's efficient theoretically by saving process and compute time doing them at the same time.

**Cons**

1. In reality, the process time that is saved is likely negligible (as mentioned by Norbert). You are still doing the validation check either way. In addition, processing time is wasted if an error was found.
2. The data integrity can be comprised. It could be possible that the JSON becomes corrupt when processing it this way.
3. The code is not as clear. When reading the business logic, it may not be as apparent what is happening because validation logic is mixed in.

What it really boils down to is **Accuracy** vs **Speed**. They generally have an inverse relationship. As you become more accurate and validate your JSON, you may have to compromise some on speed. This is really only noticeable in large data sets as computers are really fast these days. It is up to you to decide what is more important given how accurate you think you data may be when receiving it or whether that extra second or so is crucial. In some cases, it does matter (i.e. with the stock market and healthcare applications, milliseconds matter) and both are highly important. It is in those cases, that as you increase one, for example accuracy, you may have to increase speed by getting a higher performant machine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The first approach is more robust, but does not have to be noticeably more expensive. It becomes way less expensive even when you are able to abort the parsing process due to errors: Your business logic usually takes >90% of the resources in a process, so if you have an error % of 10%, you are already resource neutral. If you optimize the validation process so that the validations from the business process are performed upfront, your error rate might be much lower (like 1 in 20 to 1 in 100) to stay resource neutral.

For an example on an implementation assuming upfront data validation, look at GSON (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

GSON works as follows: Every part of the JSON can be cast into an object. This object is typed or contains typed data:
Sample object (JAVA used as example language):

```
public class someInnerDataFromJSON {
    String name;
    String address;
    int housenumber;
    String buildingType;
    // Getters and setters
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name=name; }
    //etc.
}
```

The data parsed by GSON is by using the model provided, already type checked.
This is the first point where your code can abort.

After this exit point assuming the data confirmed to the model, you can validate if the data is within certain limits. You can also write that into the model.

Assume for this buildingType is a list:

- Single family house
- Multi family house
- Apartment

You can check data during parsing by creating a setter which checks the data, or you can check it after parsing in a first set of your business rule application. The benefit of first checking the data is that your later code will have less exception handling, so less and easier to understand code.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitively go for validation before processing.

Let's say you receive some `json` data with **10** variables of which you expect:

- the first 5 variables to be of type ***string***
- 6 and 7 are supposed to be ***integers***
- 8, 9 and 10 are supposed to be ***arrays***

You can do a quick variable type validation before you start processing any of this data and return a validation error response if one of the ten fails.

```
foreach($data as $varName => $varValue){
    $varType = gettype($varValue);
    if(!$this->isTypeValid($varName, $varType)){
        // return validation error
    }
}

// continue processing
```

Think of the scenario where you are directly processing the data and then the 10th value turns out to be of invalid type. The processing of the previous 9 variables was a waste of resources since you end up returning some validation error response anyway. On top of that you have to rollback any changes already persisted to your storage.

I only use variable type in my example but I would suggest full validation (length, max/min values, etc) of all variables before processing any of them.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the first option would be the way to go. The only reason why you might need to think of the second option is if you were dealing with JSON data which was tens of MBs large or more.

In other words, only if you are trying to stream JSON and process it on the fly, you will need to think about second option.

Assuming that you are dealing with few hundred KB at most per JSON, you can just go for option one.

Here are some steps you could follow:

1. Go for a JSON parser like GSON that would just convert your entire
   JSON input into the corresponding Java domain model object. (If GSON
   doesn't throw an exception, you can be sure that the JSON is
   perfectly valid.)
2. Of course, the objects which were constructed using GSON in step 1
   may not be in a functionally valid state. For example, functional
   checks like mandatory fields and limit checks would have to be done.
3. For this, you could define a validateState method which repeatedly
   validates the states of the object itself and its child objects.

Here is an example of a `validateState` method:

```
public void validateState(){ 
    //Assume this validateState is part of Customer class.

    if(age<12 || age>150) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age should be in the range 12 to 120");
    if(age<18 && (guardianId==null || guardianId.trim().equals("")) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Guardian id is mandatory for minors");

    for(Account a:customer.getAccounts()){
        a.validateState(); //Throws appropriate exceptions if any inconsistency in state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends entirely on your use case.

If you expect all calls to originate in trusted clients then the upfront schema validation should be implement so that it is activated only when you set a debug flag.

However, if your server delivers public api services then you should validate the calls upfront. This isn't just a performance issue - your server will likely be scrutinized for security vulnerabilities by your customers, hackers, rivals, etc.

If your server delivers private api services to non-trusted clients (e.g., in a closed network setup where it has to integrate with systems from 3rd party developers), then you should at least run upfront those checks that will save you from getting blamed for someone else's goofs.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your requirements. But in general I'd always go for **#1**.

**Few considerations**:

For consistency I'd use method **#1**, for performance **#2**. However when using **#2** you have to take into account that rolling back in case of non valid input may become complicated in the future, as the logic changes.

Json validation should not take that long. In python you can use **ujson** for parsing json strings which is a *ultrafast C implementation* of the **json** python module.

For validation, I use the **jsonschema** python module which makes json validation easy.

**Another approach**:

if you use **jsonschema**, you can validate the json request in steps. I'd perform an initial validation of the most common/important parts of the json structure, and validate the remaining parts along the business logic path. This would allow to write simpler json schemas and therefore more lightweight.

**The final decision**:

If (and only if) this decision is critical I'd implement both solutions, time-profile them in right and wrong input condition, and weight the results depending on the wrong input frequency. Therefore:

- **1c** = average time spent with method 1 on **c**orrect input
- **1w** = average time spent with method 1 on **w**rong input
- **2c** = average time spent with method 2 on **c**orrect input
- **2w** = average time spent with method 2 on **w**rong input
- CR = **c**orrect input **r**ate (or frequency)
- WR = **w**rong input **r**ate (or frequency)

  ```
  if ( 1c * CR ) + ( 1w * WR) <= ( 2c * CR ) + ( 2w * WR):
      chose method 1
  else:
      chose method 2
  ```